# Differentiability over an arbitrary set

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, derivatives, definition

On page 27 of Lee's *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds* he states

> a map from an arbitrary subset $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$ is said to be smooth if in a neighborhood of each point of $A$ it admits an extension to a smooth map defined on an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ (see Appendix C, p. 645).

The section which the author is probably pointing to in Appendix C reads:

> If $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ is an arbitrary subset, a function $F:A\to\mathbb{R}^m$ is said to be smooth on $A$ if it admits a smooth extension to an open neighborhood of each point, or more precisely, if for every $x\in A$, there exist an open subset $U_x\subseteq  R^n$ containing $x$ and a smooth function $\hat{F}:U_x\to\mathbb{R}^m$ that agrees
> with $F$ on $U_x\cap A$.

**What is meant by the above definition?**

---

My particular issue is the following: if $U_x$ need not be contained in $A$, then the value of the derivative will not be well-defined for some sets e.g.
$$f:\{0\}\to\mathbb{R}$$
may be extended in multiple ways *regardless* of the value of $f(0)$.

If, on the other hand, $U_a$ is contained in $A$, then differentiability remains only defined for open sets, not arbitrary ones.

Thus neither case seems to portray what the author is saying.

Comment: The definition **does not** talk about the value of derivative. It only says what it means for the function to be differentiable. In particular it can have multiple extensions, with different derivative values. It doesn't contradict the definition at all.

Comment: @freakish I see. Perhaps it's because I need to read further, but at first sight it strikes me as odd to speak of a function being differentiable while its derivative having no well-defined value

Comment: If it bothers you so much then use the phrase “locally smoothly extendible”. This will dissuade you from trying to assign a value to derivative.

Comment: @Sam of course once the subset is more complicated (e.g. not discrete) values won't be arbitrary and we will be able to say more about them. Still rarely the case that it is a single value unless $A$ is dense in open. Yeah, counterintuitive but it is how it is.